# JDBC connection fails to SAP Hana Cloud: "RTEException: -708 Receive of connect failed."

Tags: jdbc, hana

Similar to https://answers.sap.com/questions/12675326/sap-dbtech-jdbc-708-receive-of-connect-fail.html

Connection to SAP Hana Cloud fails with the error "RTEException: -708 Receive of connect failed."

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
java -version
```

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar -V
```

package package com.sap.db.jdbc, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.4, SAP HANA JDBC Driver, SAP SE, 1.120.05-8c23c50e159e9883edab0e2ebdd4e02c5919cd08

```
java -jar ngdbc.jar -u DBADMIN,PASSWORD -n BIG-IDENTIFIER.hana.trial-us10.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443 -d test -o encrypt=true -o validatecertificate=false
```

(the certificate is imported, and the error occurs even without the parameters encrypt and validatecertificate)

**Contents of trace log:**

ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057

Process-ID: 320850

package package com.sap.db.jdbc, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.4, SAP HANA JDBC Driver, SAP SE, 1.120.05-8c23c50e159e9883edab0e2ebdd4e02c5919cd08 on Java 11.0.15

---- Thread 1eb44e46 main Timestamp: 2022-09-29 09:50:03.162

new Connection 'jdbc:sap://BIG-IDENTIFIER.hana.trial-us10.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443'

password=****

databaseName=test

host=BIG-IDENTIFIER....

options=

cmd=Select top 1 42 as "connect test" fro...

user=DBADMIN

HOSTLIST: [BIG-IDENTIFIER.hana.trial-us10.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443,]

new RTEException: -708 Receive of connect failed.

whereAmIjava.lang.Throwable

at com.sap.db.util.Tracer.whereAmI(Tracer.java:280)

at com.sap.db.rte.comm.RTEException.(RTEException.java:51)

at com.sap.db.rte.comm.BasicSocketComm.receiveInfoRequest(BasicSocketComm.java:587)

at com.sap.db.rte.comm.BasicSocketComm.doInfoRequest(BasicSocketComm.java:84)

at com.sap.db.rte.comm.BasicSocketComm.connectDB(BasicSocketComm.java:187)

at com.sap.db.rte.comm.SocketComm$1.open(SocketComm.java:47)

at com.sap.db.jdbc.topology.Topology.getSession(Topology.java:88)

at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver.openByURL(Driver.java:1216)

at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:313)

at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver.main(Driver.java:858)

using null

=> FAILED

---

any thoughts on the why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is HANA Cloud Trial, I don't think, that you should use `-d` to specify a tenant database name. Please try to remove this parameter as you may be trying to connect to a non-existing tenant database. You can also refer to [this tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-jdbc.html).

Second thing to consider is the allowlist for IP addresses. Per default connections are blocked if you have not added your client ip to the allowlist. More details can be found in [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/30/allow-connections-to-sap-hana-cloud-instance-from-selected-ip-addresses-using-the-command-line/).

Last but not least, please check if your are using the latest version of `ngdb.jar`. It can be obtained on [this site](https://tools.eu1.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools).

Comment: nothing yet. Even without the -d parameter, the same error is raised. The allowlist is configured to accept all ips (testing purposes)

Comment: Can you try to get the latest ngdbc.jar here: https://tools.eu1.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools

Comment: That did the trick, updating to the latest version makes the connection works. I'll edit your answer to include the suggestion to update the version and accept it. Thanks a lot!